# linux: Is there a way to dump the task run queue?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, monitoring, scheduling

I'm facing a [strange extreme load issue on idle conditions](https://serverfault.com/questions/792738/linux-extreme-load-on-idle-cpu).

**Is there a way to directly dump the linux process scheduler run queue?** 
E.g. when `sar -q` outputs 400 as `runq-sz`, to get those 400 PIDs?

`ps`, `top` and friends seems to be too "slow" to take an instant snapshot, because they're showing only a few processes in `D` or `R` state.

Comment: I'm not sure if the scheduler performs any logging (actually, i think it may not log any kernel messages and i'm talking crap) but you can try booting with `log_level=6` (or maybe even 7).  Just be prepared to get a **lot** of messages in dmesg.

Comment: The run queue includes threads (a thread is defined as a "light weight process"). Use `top -H` and `ps -eLf` to show them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to dump the run queue, but you might be able to get some other info using `perf`. Eg if a storm of new processes are being created, you can trace them with

```
perf record -e sched:sched_process_exec -a
```

Stop the recording with control-C, and look at the results with `perf report`.  You might also look through the simple but powerful scripts based on `perf` that [Brendan Gregg](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) has gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Looking straight at the kernel source code, you can browse tasks like the following.

```c
struct task_struct *process, *thread;
int cnt = 0;

rcu_read_lock();
for_each_process_thread(process, thread) {
    task_lock(thread);

/* do something with the task properties:

     thread->state;
     thread->wake_cpu;
     thread->pid;
     thread->comm;
*/

    task_unlock(thread);
    cnt++;
}
rcu_read_unlock();
```

The most important part is to *lock* the tasks RCU at entry and *unlock* at exit.
You will code this dump in a kernel module and provide a mean to retrieve the list in a user-space command.

I suggest you to read and enhance to your needs my example in the GitHub @ [dumptask](https://github.com/cyring/dumptask)